# Signed Apk not found in directory React Native - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am using react-native `0.60` version and my Gradle version is `5.4.1`. Now I'm trying to extract signed apk. When I execute, all the steps the apk build successfully. But When I checking this path `F:\React Native\AwesomeProject1\android\app\build\outputs\apk`

please check this screenshot https://prnt.sc/p391mr.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to generate release apk

```
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

**Note that** `--variant=release` is only available if you've set up signing as described above.

You can kill any running packager instances, since all your framework and JavaScript code is bundled in the APK's assets.

Please follow this link

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

You using this command

```
$ cd android 
$ ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

You only generate android apk bundle (AAB)not an apk.The generated AAB can be found under

```
android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app.aab
```

Comment: but how to install aab file in my mobile, is this possible to convert aab to apk

Comment: No there is **not possible to convert aab to apk** and you cannot install aab file into device. If you want to install app into device you need to generate apk.

Comment: But aab file is enough to upload on Google play store right?

Comment: Yes but Android App Bundles(aab) is a publishing format. Android devices require .apk files to install applications.
The PlayStore or any other source that you're installing from needs to extract apks from the bundle, sign each one and then install them specific to the target device.

Answer (score 0):

On windows if you're going to use `gradlew` directly you need to run the windows variant of the command. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

So you should be running `gradlew bundleRelease`

From your screenshot you are running the *nix variant of `./gradlew bundleRelease`. Note the removal of the leading `./` in the Windows version.